# Give an example of absolutely continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $fg$ is not absolutely continuous when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of absolutely continuous functions $f,g\in AC(\mathbb{R})$ such that $fg$ is not absolutely continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously the counterexample should guarantee that at least one of $f$ or $g$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $f(x)=x^2$ is not absolutely continuous on $\mathbb R$.